# Javascript not rendering correctly when accessed via https

Tags: javascript, http

Relatively self-taught user over here, so not sure if this is basic, but Google is indexing our site via https. Which, when you click to get to the home page, is not rendering a section that has a javascript on it. All the text is laid on top of each other, rather than rotating through.

However, if you go to our home page with the address http:// the java is working fine. Any help correcting this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Press F12 and read your console. something isn't loading, most likely because you're using absolute links rather than relative links, resulting in assets loading from http instead of https.

Comment: if you use absolute links ommit the http protocol

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve your JS over https as well, because when your https page refers to http content it is considered as insecure data, and your browser won't load it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using absolute urls for your scripts. or cdn without https. if yes, use relative urls for your local script and use https:// for cdn script paths. You can simply define //cdn path without http: or https: so that the script will load according to the site path.